# CSS :not pseudo class

Tags: css, css-selectors, selector

I would like to apply a certain style to all descendants of an element except some.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve : http://jsfiddle.net/f8FLe/

```
.root * :not(.nested) {
    color: green;
}


<div class="root">

    <span>Span 1</span>
    <div class="nested">
        <span>Span 2.1</span>
        <span>Span 2.2</span>
    </div>    
    <span>Span 3</span>

</div>
```

In this example, I try to color all fonts to green except those that are descendants of the div element with 'nested' class.

In that purpose, I tried to use the ":not" pseudo element but it doesn't work. 
Do someone know why ?

Comment: Color is inherited. You'd need to override the color of the parent by setting a color on the child.

Comment: it does not work here because color is inherited from parent, add somewhere a class .nested and give it the color you wish it to keep.

Comment: removing the `*` may work as what you want (the span 1 and span 3 should be colored as `green`)

Answer (score 0):

Because your inner `<span>`s... they are `:not(.nested)`, because they don't have that class.

One thing I like to do - particularly with lists, is something like this:

```
<ul class="root">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>Item 2.1</li>
      <li>Item 2.2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

With that structure (which is very similar to what you have, by the way), you can do this:

```css
.root>li {color:green}
.root ul>li {color:blue} /* nested list */
/* you can also do... */
.root>li>ul>li {color:red} /* specifically one level of nesting */
```

Comment: Even when I try to put 'nested' class on my <span>'s , that doesn't work .. :-/

Comment: @RianaRambonimanana [Really?](http://jsfiddle.net/f8FLe/1/) Try [the right selector](http://jsfiddle.net/f8FLe/2/)

Comment: set a color to .nested and it will not take parent's color :)

Comment: Thanks Niet, the selector you suggested works indeed, but in my actual problem, I do not want to put '.nested' class in all div.nested descendants ... I would like to write something like :not(.nested *), but it doesn't work ..

Comment: That why I suggested the use of the `>` combinator.

Comment: The > combinator is not enough as I have to select ALL descendants of the element with '.nested' class and I do not know in advance what kind of elements they are ..

Comment: In your original HTML, just `.root>span` would be perfectly adequate to make your target spans green without affecting the nested `<div>`.

Comment: Yes but it was just an example to expose the problem and I choose a simple one .. In my real case, I must be able to exclude all descendants of an element.

Answer (score 0):

its about inheritance and about sibling the right tags.

You rules says , if class = . nested , do not apply color.

inside div.nested , you have 2 span with no class.
either you do not wrap text in tags http://jsfiddle.net/f8FLe/6/, or you give the nested class to each tag you do not want to apply color http://jsfiddle.net/f8FLe/5/.

```
.root * :not(.nested) {
    color: green;
}
```

playground HTML:

```
<div class="nested">
        <span>not nested</span><!-- green -->
        nested<!-- not green -->
        <span class="nested"> nested</span><!-- not green -->
        <span class="nested"> nested</span><!-- not green -->
         nested
    </div>
```

Comment: The parent has no colour either. It's not inheriting from anything.

Comment: child are not being selected by the rule, they do not have the class .nested , confusing indeed.

Answer (score 0):

With your tag structure I would use something like this:

```
.root *{
    color: green;
}
.nested span{
    color: black;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f8FLe/7/

Your problem is the `span`s contained by `.nested` don't have the `.nested` class (as Niet the Dark Absol says)

Comment: Smart workaround ! I'll try it on my problem, thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

This works: http://jsfiddle.net/f8FLe/8/

```
.root > *:not(.nested) {
    color: green;
}
```